# QGIS Standalone C++ Application with Qt: "The program has unexpectedly finished"

Tags: qgis, qt

I'm trying to develop an Standalone Application with Qt and QGIS API.

There are several code examples that should work, but they don't.

The Problem is that everytime I use "QgsApplication" the application Output says: "The program has unexpectedly finished."

Even this simple code does not work:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include "qgsapplication.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
}
```

My Project.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Project
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L"C:/QGIS Building/lib" -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/QGIS Building/include"

DEFINES +=      CORE_EXPORT=""
DEFINES +=      GUI_EXPORT=""
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? How are you linking this?

Comment: No I haven't tried a Debugger yet.
I added the linking to my question.

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Yes I did. In my case it was just a bug in the QGis version I downloaded.

Comment: As June 2020 I have very similar question at:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365057/using-qgis-c-api-in-custom-gis-application

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems, when I try to run a standalone QGis App. Important is that you call QApplication at first and then set context path for QGIS with

```
   QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("/usr", true);
```

(in LINUX) before you call.

```
   QgsApplication::initQgis();
```

A program initialisation that works for me looks like this.

```cpp
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <qgsapplication.h>
 #include "mainwindow.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   // 1. Initialize App
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("/usr", true);
   QgsApplication::initQgis();

    //2. App start
    MainWindow win(config, db);
    win.show();
    int result = app.exec();

    //3. Qgis free libs
    QgsApplication::exitQgis();

    //4. And say goodby
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: It's true what you say, it has to be coded in this order.

But my Problem was a bug in the QGis Version, after I tried the latest version all my problems were gone.

Comment: sir how you are creating this application Like its simple visual studio project in which you are including qgis librarie?

Comment: I guess, the library declarion follows the qmake syntax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake,  not visual studio configs.