# QGIS 3 C++ API, QgsApplication crash

Tags: qgis-3, c++, qt

I'm trying to create a simple application using QGIS 3 SDK. I have used osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe for installing QGIS, and I have also installed **qgis-dev** and **qgis-ltr-dev** and **Qt5**. I have set up my .pro file like this:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\include" \
                "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\bin"

LIBS += -L"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\lib" -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui -lqgis_app

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

and the main.cpp is like this:

```
#include <qgsapplication.h>

#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qDebug() << "*** QGS Application Instance Created *** ";

    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
    int exitCode= app.exec();

    return exitCode;
}
```

I run my code in this enviroment:

```
Windows 10 
Qt 5.15.1(MSVC 2019) 
Qt Creator 4.13.1  
QGIS 3.x.x
```

This code is compiled correctly. But, the problem is when I run it, the program crash even before entering the main function. When I comment the line `QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);`, the crash does not happen. I believe there is some problem with linking the QGIS to my application.

How can I fix this?

Have I done something wrong?

Haven't I considered something in setting up the environment?

Comment: Not enough confident with C++ but I've made some PR to make QGIS C++ demos work with latest QGIS. Not merged and only tested on Ubuntu but could help maybe https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Code-Examples/pulls

Comment: Thanks for your comment; this link is handy for me as a start point for using QGIS3 C++ API; I wonder why they don't update the sample code for QGIS3.

Comment: It takes work and there is no one dedicated to it, the repo readme says it is there for archival reasons only. This means *you* can be the guy to make an awesome set of working C++ examples as you learn! Others will be able to build upon your foundation! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/365166/134178). But a new problem is raised.

I put a breakpoint on the line **QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true)** and the debugger pops up this:

[image]

And at the end of the program, when the line **return app.exec();** run, this warning is displayed on the console.

> QApplication::exec: Please instantiate the QApplication object first

PS: I explain the problem completely [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/397252/134178).