# Problem on running a sample code of QGIS3 C++ API

Tags: qgis-3, api, c++, qt, standalone

I have written a code using QGIS 3 C++ API. But there are runtime errors. My environment is:

> Windows 10 64bit
> Qt 5.15.1(MSVC 2019)
> Qt Creator 4.13.1
> QGIS 3.x.x
> using osgeo4w-setup-x86_64.exe, and installing **qgis-dev**, **qgis-ltr-dev**, and **Qt5** within QGIS3 SDK

My **.pro** file is:

```
QT       += core gui XML

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\include

LIBS += -L"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\lib" -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui

DEFINES+=CORE_EXPORT=
DEFINES+=GUI_EXPORT=

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

my **main.cpp**

```
01 #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
02 #include <cmath>
03 
04 #include <QString>
05 #include <QApplication>
06 #include <QWidget>
07 #include <QJsonObject>
08 #include <QDomDocument>
09
10 #include <qgsapplication.h>
11 #include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
12 #include <qgssinglesymbolrenderer.h>
13 #include <qgsproject.h>
14 #include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
15 #include <qgssymbol.h>
16 #include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
17 
18 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
19 {
20    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
21
22    QString myPluginsDir        = "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis-ltr-dev\\plugins";
23    QString myLayerPath         = "D:/QGIS/QGIS-Sample-Data-master/QGIS-Sample-Data -master/qgis_sample_data/shapefiles/airports.shp";
24    QString myLayerBaseName     = "airports";
25    QString myProviderName      = "ogr";
26    // Instantiate Provider Registry
27    QgsProviderRegistry::instance(myPluginsDir);
28    // create a maplayer instance
29    QgsVectorLayer * mypLayer = new QgsVectorLayer(myLayerPath, myLayerBaseName, myProviderName);
30
31    QgsSingleSymbolRenderer *mypRenderer = new QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(QgsSymbol::defaultSymbol(mypLayer->geometryType()));
32    QList <QgsMapLayer *> layers;
33    mypLayer->setRenderer(mypRenderer);
34    if (mypLayer->isValid())
35    {
36       qDebug("Layer is valid");
37    }
38    else
39    {
40       qDebug("Layer is NOT valid");
41    }
42
43    QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayer(mypLayer);
44    // Add the Layer to the Layer Set
45    layers.append(mypLayer);
46
47    // Create the Map Canvas
48    QgsMapCanvas * mypMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas();
49    mypMapCanvas->setExtent(mypLayer->extent());
50    mypMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
51    mypMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor(0, 0, 0));
52    mypMapCanvas->freeze(false);
53    // Set the Map Canvas Layer Set
54    mypMapCanvas->setLayers(layers);
55    mypMapCanvas->setVisible(true);
56    mypMapCanvas->refresh();
57
58    // Start the Application Event Loop
59    return app.exec();
60 }
```

during debugging when reachs line 20 (`QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);`), a popup appears like this:

[image]

after that when reachs line 27 (`QgsProviderRegistry::instance(myPluginsDir);`), on console this errors will appear:

> ......\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(195) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [5511ms] Checking C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr-dev/plugins/grassplugin7.dll: ...invalid (lib not loadable): Cannot load library C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\plugins\grassplugin7.dll: The specified module could not be found.
> ......\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(195) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [9ms] Checking C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr-dev/plugins/grassprovider7.dll: ...invalid (lib not loadable): Cannot load library C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\plugins\grassprovider7.dll: The specified module could not be found.
> ......\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(195) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [7ms] Checking C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr-dev/plugins/grassrasterprovider7.dll: ...invalid (lib not loadable): Cannot load library C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\plugins\grassrasterprovider7.dll: The specified module could not be found.
> ......\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(230) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [12ms] Checking C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr-dev/plugins/oracleprovider.dll: ...invalid (no metadata returned)
> ......\src\core\qgsproviderregistry.cpp(245) : (QgsProviderRegistry::init) [19ms] Loaded 22 providers (DB2;OAPIF;WFS;arcgisfeatureserver;arcgismapserver;delimitedtext;gdal;geonode;gpx;mdal;memory;mesh_memory;mssql;ogr;ows;postgres;postgresraster;spatialite;vectortile;virtual;wcs;wms)

then on line 48 (`QgsMapCanvas * mypMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas();`), the below error displays several times:

> Exception at 0x7ffe8bad4b89, code: 0xe06d7363: C++ exception, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) (first chance) in proj_8_1!osgeo::proj::File::~File

And the previous popup will appear again.

[image]

Finally, at line 50(`return app.exec();`), this message appears:

> QApplication::exec: Please instantiate the QApplication object first

And then, -1 is returned, and the program closes immediately.

What does it make this happen? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Does `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\plugins\grassplugin7.dll` really there in this exact place?

Comment: @ThomasG77 yes, I have checked it, and it does exist that dll file in the path

Comment: Look at your DLL dependencies using https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies (inheritor of dependency Walker) You may have the various DLLs but not the DLLs depending from the entries DLLs like grassplugin7.dll

Comment: @ThomasG77 I have used the dependency walker. Honestly, I didn't understand what is going on and how to use that. Also, I have changed the path from 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr-dev\...' to 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\...'. The error related to grass7.dll didn't happen, but the problem and the runtime crash are persisted.